# Creating new lines in string using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string that looks this `"Hello Name, Choose one of the options below.\n\n1. Phones\n\n2. Computers"`
When the output is returned, I do not see the newlines taking effect. What could I be missing ?

**JS**

```js
var message = "Hello Name, Choose one of the options below.\n\n1. Phones\n\n2. Computers"
console.log(messsage);
$('.item').val(message);
```

Comment: What element is used for `class="item"`?

Comment: You *can* insert blank lines in a text with `.val()`, but *only* if the target is a multiline input field, like `<textarea>`.

Comment: Your `console.log` doesn't work because `messsage` is not the same as `message`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the new lines with <br> 
The reason is that in HTML new lines are made by the <br> tag

```js
var message = "Hello Name, Choose one of the options below.<br>\n1. Phones<br>\n2. Computers"
$('.item').html(message);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item"></div>
```

When you use \n

```js
var message = "Hello Name, Choose one of the options below.\n\n1. Phones\n\n2. Computers"
    $('.item').html(message);
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="item"></div>
```

Comment: You've changed the code of the question. It was `.val(message)` and you've made it `.html(message)`. They are not the same.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Well that's true I assumed OP wants to write to the html. In a textarea the new lines will applied properly but you are right it is important what the `.class item` element is.